How to use multiple processes of Selenium with one user-data-dir?
I'm trying to use Selenium to scrap and do some actions on a list of URLs.
The list itself contains some thousands of URLs.
So, I'm trying to use a pool of processes to manage multiple instances of Google Chrome. And, I need to specify the user's directory to access to its cookies with the argument --user-data-dir.
But I've got the error message:
Message: session not created
from unknown error: Could not remove old devtools port file. Perhaps the given user-data-dir at C:\Users\ilpla\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data is still attached to a running Chrome or Chromium process

Is there a way to open multiples instances of Google Chrome without having this error?
Here is the code I'm trying to use:
#!/bin/python3
import argparse
import pathlib
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from tqdm import tqdm
from multiprocessing import Pool
from colorama import Fore

# Class for the album
class Album:
    """
    Class for the album.
    """
    def __init__(self, id, title, productUrl, mediaItemsCount):
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.productUrl = productUrl
        self.mediaItemsCount = mediaItemsCount

# Class for the albums list
class AlbumList:
    """
    Class for the album list.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.albums = []

def delete_empty_albums(location: pathlib.Path, profile: pathlib.Path, threads: int):
    """
    Delete the albums with no items in them.

    Parameters:
        location: pathlib.Path
            The path to the browser location to use.
        profile: pathlib.Path
            The path to the user profile to use.
        threads: int
            The number of threads to use.
    """
    # Get the empty albums
    albums = list_empty_albums()

    # Create the pool of drivers
    pool = Pool(processes = threads)
    try:
        # Loop on the empty albums
        for album in tqdm(albums.albums,
                desc = "Deleting empty albums",
                unit = "album",
                position = 0,
                leave = True):
            # If the album has no items, remove it
            if album.mediaItemsCount == 0:
                # Remove the empty album
                try:
                    tqdm.write(f"""{Fore.BLUE} Remove the empty album: "{album.title}"…""")
                    tqdm.write(f"\tURL: {album.productUrl}{Fore.RESET}")

                    # Use the browser to remove the album
                    pool.apply_async(delete_album,
                        args = (album.productUrl, location, profile),
                        callback = lambda _: delete_album_success(album.title, album.id),
                        error_callback = lambda e: delete_album_error(album.title, album.id, e)
                    )
                except Exception as e:
                    tqdm.write(f"""{Fore.RED}⚠️ Failed to remove album: "{album.title}".""")
                    tqdm.write(f"\tError: {e}")
                    tqdm.write(f"\tID: {album.id}")
                    tqdm.write(f"\tURL: {album.productUrl}{Fore.RESET}")
    except Exception as e:
        tqdm.write(f"{Fore.RED}⚠️ Failed to delete albums: {e}.{Fore.RESET}")
    finally:
        # Close the pool
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

def list_empty_albums() -> AlbumList:
    """
    List all the empty albums.
    """
    # Initialize the album list
    album_list = AlbumList()

    # ...

def delete_album(album_productUrl: str, location: pathlib.Path, profile: pathlib.Path) -> bool:
    """
    Delete the album with the given product URL.
    """
    driver = browser_driver(location, profile)

    try:
        # Open the album page
        driver.get(album_productUrl)

        # Wait for the page to load
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)

        # Click on the top right button
        ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(750, 30).click().perform()
        time.sleep(0.2)

        # Click on the "Delete the album" menu item
        ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(0, 60).click().perform()
        time.sleep(0.2)

        # Click on the "Delete" button
        ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(-150, 200).click().perform()
        time.sleep(1)

        # Wait for the page to load
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)

        return True

    finally:
        # Close the browser
        driver.quit()

def browser_driver(location: pathlib.Path, profile: pathlib.Path) -> webdriver.Chrome:
    """
    Create a browser driver.
    """
    # Create the driver for the browser
    options = Options()
    if location:
        options.binary_location = str(location)
    options.headless = True

    # Set the user data location
    options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={profile}")

    # Disable the browser logs in the console
    options.add_argument("--silent")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])

    # Set the window size
    options.add_argument("--window-size=800,600")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
    driver.set_window_size(800, 600)

    return driver

def delete_album_success(album_title: str, album_id: str):
    """
    Called when album deletion is successful.
    """
    tqdm.write(f"""{Fore.GREEN}️ Successfully removed empty album: "{album_title}".""")
    tqdm.write(f"\tID: {album_id}{Fore.RESET}")

def delete_album_error(album_title: str, album_id: str, error: Exception):
    """
    Called when album deletion fails.
    """
    tqdm.write(f"""{Fore.RED}⚠️ Failed to remove album: "{album_title}".""")
    tqdm.write(f"\tID: {album_id}{Fore.RESET}")
    tqdm.write(f"\tError: {error}{Fore.RESET}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Command line options
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Delete empty albums")
    parser.add_argument("-l", "--location",
        required = False,
        type = pathlib.Path,
        help = "Path to the browser location to use. Work only with Google Chrome or Chromium.")
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--profile",
        required = False,
        type = pathlib.Path,
        help = "Path to the user profile to use.")
    parser.add_argument("-t", "--threads",
        required = False,
        type = int,
        default = 5,
        help = "Number of threads to use (default: 5).")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # ...

    delete_empty_albums(args.location, args.profile, args.threads)

